# Extract the name of the workbook where the formula is saved and not the name of the workbook currently in use

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to find an excel or Power query M (not vba) formula to extract the filename of the workbook where this formula is executed.
Internet seems to know only one :

> =MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1)

unfortunately this formula provides only the name of the workbook **currently in use**,
so, if I use a second workbook before executing my function in my first workbook, the name given by this formula will be the name of my second file, which causes terrible mistakes.

Is there a more practical way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the second (*reference*) parameter of `CELL`, then the formula will be "locked" to the sheet/file in question:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename",A1))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)
```

This is discussed in the [`CELL`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) docs as well as by Chip Pearson [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FileFolderNames.aspx).