# Is there an Excel formula using CONCAT, MID, FIND, CELL, and (?) functions to Obtain the name of the Current Workbook for a column header?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet, columnheader

What I want is to have a column header above an indexing column, such that it would display "PK_[SheetName]".

I am trying to use a formula that can be copied and pasted in cells on different sheets, like a "template" formula. The formula will reside in different locations (different row, column) on different worksheets within a workbook. In this case, my workbook has, on each tab, an "Index" (ascending integers starting at 1) for each row of information to the right of Column A.  I also have a need for a way to reference the current cell for other indexes within the same sheet, which have a hierarchy as well (e.g., if cell adjacent to or might have particular strings (e.g., the "hierarchy index cell" only starts an index if the cell above it and to the right has a string of text, like "Items", and continues in its own column until a range of cells are blank (presumably the end of the table). For the main index, which I'll call the Primary Key (PK), the counter starts at 1 and increases to the end of the range of the information.  (I'm not complicating it further by having it check if the cells are blank for PK; I'm only using the PK for a fixed number of cells, which vary from sheet to sheet). But I want the column heading above the PK index to incorporate the sheet name.

I know that `CONCAT`, `MID`, `FIND` and `CELL` to obtain the current workbook name. I am trying to NOT have to create separate defined "Names" for each PK column heading on each sheet.  I'm not savvy enough to know if there's a way to define a Name for a cell that could vary in position on each sheet of the workbook, and have it pull the tab name from the `CELL` function uniquely for each worksheet.

I have tried looking at MS Support pages for [`CELL`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) and [`ADDRESS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) functions, have found a thread that comes close but doesn't address how to reference the current cell in which the function resides [Another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007114/extract-the-name-of-the-workbook-where-the-formula-is-saved-and-not-the-name-of), and another reference linked from that thread [Secondary Reference](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FileFolderNames.aspx).

What I lack is the ability to have a formula reference the "current cell".  The current formula I have is:

```
=CONCAT("PK_" & MID(CELL("filename", A23),FIND("]", CELL("filename", A23)) + 1, 255))
```

Where:

- A23 = the particular cell the PK number is in
- [worksheet name] = ThisWorksheet

The result is "PK_ThisWorksheet"

I came across the `ADDRESS` function, and tried to plug in `ADDRESS(COLUMN(), ROW(), 4)` where "A23" exists:

```
=CONCAT("PK_"&MID(CELL("filename",ADDRESS(COLUMN(), ROW(), 4)),FIND("]",CELL("filename",ADDRESS(COLUMN(), ROW(), 4)))+1,255))
```

But I got the "There's a problem with this formula" Yellow Exclamation Point Triangle Warning, and can't get any further. I was expecting it to come back with "PK_ThisWorksheet".

Again, if there's a workaround that doesn't involve in-cell functions, I'm all ears, but I would very much prefer a solution that uses functions for the sake of "ease", both in usage/repeat usage as well as in teaching others who might have to manage the spreadsheet after me.

Comment: `I'm not savvy enough to know if there's a way to define a Name for a cell that could vary in position on each sheet of the workbook` - and yet that's [what you should do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176154/11683), if I understand your problem correctly. Then you can copy and paste the formulas that refer to the local name, and they will mean different things on different sheets.

Comment: why do you need concat() when you use & to join the parts?

Comment: @GSerg; Thanks; I went into the Names Manager, created a New Name, where Name = "PK_ColHeading", "Scope" = Workbook, Comment = "Refers to cell (address may change on each worksheet) for use in Column Name heading.  Value will change based on worksheet.", Refers to = ...?  What should go here since the reference would necessarily change?  It defaults to "=ThisWorkbook!$A$1, but the reference would be different on each sheet (with a different tab name) and a different cell reference (Other than A1)?
@SolarMike; I just did...is it better to use & and/or JOIN?

Comment: You should have used Worksheet as the scope. And you put the address on that sheet. Or you don't go there at all and do as suggested in the last sentence of the linked answer.

Comment: @GSerg; just a note, I tried the first solution, creating PK_ColHeading to point to the worksheet; in Sheet 1 it worked fine ("PK_Sheet 1"), but when I went to other sheets to copy & paste (e.g., Sheet 2, Sheet 3, Sheet 4), all instances on each worksheet came back as "PK_Sheet 1".  The other solution looks like VB code in a module?  I'll give it a try next.  Was hoping for a non-VB solution, but if that's what I gotta do, I'll do it.  Thanks!  (Will advise when I succeed).

Comment: There was no VBA solution. You were supposed to create a name in each worksheet where it is needed. Did you do that?